# DataTables showing 'false' in columns where JOIN query records do not exist

Tags: jquery, cakephp, datatables

I have an application which is using DataTables 1.10.16 in 'serverSide' mode.

The source of my data is a JSON feed produced by CakePHP.

The query which populates my table involves various SQL `JOIN` conditions. There are scenarios happening like this - the following is the JSON data produced following the query:

```
{"app_id":"ID240158", "name":"(-)-Glyceollin II", "ecs":false, "cas":"67314-98-1"}
```

In the above example `ecs` is `false` because there is no corresponding record in the 'ecs' table of my database for this particular record. The above is generated through CakePHP, but I don't want to change the way it's output because technically this is correct - there is no such EC record.

However, in my DataTable it will output as follows:

```
App ID   | Name              | EC    | CAS
-------------------------------------------------
ID240158 | (-)-Glyceollin II | false | 67314-98-1
```

All want to do is show an empty string instead of "false" in the table under the EC column.

Is this something which can be done through DataTables/jquery? Or should I deal with this on the CakePHP side? Ideally I want to do this through the clientside because I believe the JSON being produced is technically accurate for the records in the database.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery DataTables, but generally I'd say that `null` would seem like a more appropriate value to indicate that something doesn't exist.

Comment: Fixed it now. You pointed me in the right direction. The issue was that the JSON was being produced by a customised json template in Cake. Checking for the presence of the EC field and then changing it to an empty string, for the DataTable feed, fixes this. Thanks.